# using Mod Rewrite in .htaccess to get "prettify" urls working correctly

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a website which has several pages which are generated by pulling data from a database, the links to view those pages look like this.

www.mywebsite.com/article.php?id=01&title=title

and i am trying to set up a mod rewrite to get the server to display the the same webpages but using a much nicer looking url.

www.mywebsite.com/article/01/title

the line of code i have used in my .htaccess file is

```
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\+]+)/?$ /article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

now when i go back to my website and type in the following url
www.mywebsite.com/article/01/title

it displays the correct content but there is no styling attached to the page at all?

my full .htaccess is as follows

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
# Needed before any rewriting
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*(default|index)\.   (html|php|htm)\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)(default|main|index)\.(html|php|htm)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\+]+)/?$ /article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong?
many thanks

Comment: Do you use relative path to CSS files?

Comment: Add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means you have probably attached your css file with a relative path not starting by a "/", change this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<!--- TO -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
<!-- OR -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/css/style.css">
```

I don't think there is a problem with your rewrite rules, you just have virtual directories in your URL now you have to manage.